# where will this listnode point to given the situation?

Tags: java

I am confused about something regarding linked lists. If I have a list node n pointing to 10, n.next pointing to 20, n.next.next pointing to 30, list node m pointing to n, and another list node l pointing to 20, what will m.next be if I say m.next = l.next?

for example:

```
n -> 10 -> 20 -> 30
m -> n
l -> 20
```

where will m.next point to if I say:

```
m.next = l.next
```

?

Comment: What is your answer? Do you think it's correct? Why? Did you trying writing a small snippet and seeing what output you get?

Comment: I was thinking null since l.next doesn't exist. But I am not sure. I am new to listnodes.

Comment: You should try to write small program and print the list for better understanding.
l.next doesn't exist or l.next will be 20 ?

Comment: I will suggest you to use pen and paper and make inter-connections between the nodes and solve it. You'll eventually arrive at the reuslts.